# What is the opposite of "the deaf are"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, fused-head-constructions

Could someone help me with the (or "a") correct opposite of *the deaf are* (*deaf* as defined in this [National Association of the Deaf article](https://www.nad.org/resources/american-sign-language/community-and-culture-frequently-asked-questions/))?

Saying *the non-deaf are* does not sound nice.

Comment: Hearing seems an obvious choice.

Comment: "deaf" is normally an ***adjective***. The ***noun*** form ("the deaf") isn't used anywhere near as often as, say, ***The poor** [are always with us]*, and to be honest I feel the usage might be considered at the very least "insensitive / disparaging", if not actually *offensive* (I feel much the same about references to [***the negro***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+negro+is+easily+influenced%22)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Indeed, for some time _people with [name of problem or impairment]_ has been the preferred terminology, though there is still the Royal School for the Deaf in my home city. I suppose 'for people with hearing impairments' would make the name rather cumbersome.

Comment: @KateBunting: I didn't follow through, but at time of posting that comment, I half intended to do a bit of research to see whether organisations with names like the *Royal School for the Deaf* and *National Association of the Deaf* experienced pressure to consider changing their name. Unless and until it's "officially" changed, a proper noun just stays the way it is, but I'm sure you're right that in other contexts, the preferred term is *people with [name of problem or impairment]*, rather than *"the [impaired]".* Something to do with "isolating" them as a group, I guess.

Comment: @KateBunting If you read OP's link you will see that its said 'Hearing Impaired' is expressly *not* the descriptors preferred by the Deaf and Hard of Hearing community. 'Deaf and Hard of Hearing' are.

Comment: The link in your question doesn't give a noun definition of 'deaf', they use it purely as a description, 'deaf people', the deaf community' etc. They don't seem to use 'the deaf' to mean 'deaf people'. If they don't use deaf as a noun, do you still think there should be a noun form for people with hearing?

Comment: @Spagirl the webpage the OP links does have *deaf* used as a noun one time: "Nearly all organizations of *the deaf* use the term “deaf and hard of hearing,” and the NAD is no exception.

Comment: @DjinTonic taken in isolation it is ambiguous whether that is a noun phrase or an adjectival phrase. Taken in context it is absolutely clear that the phrase is a description to precede 'people' or 'community', rather than a noun to replace 'people' or 'community'.

Comment: I too thought the deaf is not a correct term to use, and had been using hearing-impaired instead, until I read the article I quoted in my question.

Comment: To clarify, this is a valid sentence: "The deaf may have trouble reading." Is there a single word that might fit here: "The [non-deaf] typically should not have trouble reading as the deaf do".

Comment: *Deaf* is not a noun in *the deaf are listening*; it is an adjective, just as in *the poor are with us always*. It is modifying a missing/assumed noun like *people* or *things*. This is a fused modifier-head construction which allows for a noun phrase that does not contain an actual noun to serve as grammatical subject, object, etc. You can tell these aren't nouns because they do not inflect as nouns: a *deaf, the *deafs, the *poors, the *sighteds, the *wearies. And they do not inflect because adjectives never inflect for number in English. So these are adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist  We don't say "the deaf *is*" but "the deaf *are*", so is there terminology for the process whereby "the + [adjective]" qualifies the adjective as a subject that takes a *plural* verb? Something in addition to "fused modifier-head"?  The silent *makes* no sound. The deaf *are* "hard of hearing" or completely unable to hear.

Comment: @TimR You can always say “the <ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ> are” with plural concord in the sense of “the <ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ> (*people / things*) are”, but what you choose to call that is a matter of your nomenclatural religion. It’s simplest to think of it as elision or omission of a plural noun like *people/things*. (Although with an omitted mass noun construed, singular concord *ɪꜱ* possible; just rare.) Clearly these are not nouns since they can be modified ᴏɴʟʏ by adverbs, never adjectives. Hence *“the partial**ly** interested are”*, never *“the ❌partial interested are”*. **Not all subjects are nouns, just NPs.**

Comment: @tchrist I'm not disagreeing, but it complicates matters that the [ahd](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=deaf), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deaf), and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/deaf) label *deaf*  in *the deaf* as a noun.

Comment: @tchrist The "no-adjectives" rule may have exceptions, for example [Like *the eminent hearing*, *the successful deaf* came from prosperous families that prized, and could provide, good education](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dancing_Without_Music/xDIk11MulDsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+successful+deaf%22&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @DjinTonic You can't really trust dictionaries for grammar, but the OED says this is still an adjective. It calls ones like these, specifically including *the deaf*,  "absolute" uses of adjectives used where a plural substantive is expected, just like they call words "attributive" uses of nouns when used to modify other nouns. Because the asker originally thought they wanted a noun, this has led answerers to be confused about why they shouldn't be able to use absolute adjectives themselves. The clue that something's funny here noun-wise is the lack of "any successful deafs" in the literature.

Answer (score 5):

**hearing**, adj. 1884   A. J. Ellis in *Athenæum* 12 Jan. 55/1   *A school..for teaching deaf-mute infants in..association with *hearing* infants.*

From the website of [The British Deaf Association](https://bda.org.uk/history/)

> Following the re-appraisal of the BDA’s role at its 1980 Congress, the BDA also turned its attention to mobilising the support of the **hearing** community.  Its aim was, and still is, to develop greater understanding throughout the UK of what deafness means, and to fundraise for its community development and campaigning programmes.

The same site consistently uses "deaf" and "hearing" only as attributive adjectives.

Comment: Thanks, but I am after a noun. Hearing as a noun, in this context, refers to the hearing ability. E.g.  "My hearing is bad".  "The deaf may have trouble reading." Is there a single word that might fit here: "The [non-deaf] typically should not have trouble reading as the deaf do".

Comment: @pengu1n *Thanks, but I am after a noun* Hmm... In "The **hearing** typically should not have trouble reading as the deaf do", **hearing** is a substantivised adjective - to all intents and purposes it is an uncountable noun. Compare "The **rich**, typically, should not have trouble reading that the **poor** do", in which "rich" and "poor" are substantivised adjectives.

Comment: But accredited examples of usages such as 'The hearing typically should not have trouble reading as the deaf do", using _hearing_ as a standalone substantive, are more appropriate.

Comment: @pengu1n. It may be unusual outside of the context of Deaf media, but I can assure you that *hearing* is used in precisely that way. (Bear in mind that there might actually be three categories: Deaf, Hearing, and Hearing Impaired. And that's not getting into the complexity of d/Deaf identity.)

Answer (score 1):

As a deaf person, I will be blunt in my answer. I would call a non-deaf person "***Hearing***". It can be both a noun or an adjective:  "*I have two hearing brothers*"  or "*Where Hearing*" (person)

Comment: Can you clarify your second example?

Comment: Hi, can you please translate ASL syntax of "where hearing person"? Understood as to be/stative verb missing?

Answer (score 0):

"Aurally-able".

[Aural](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aurally) (Merriam-Webster Dictionary): of or relating to the ear or to the sense of hearing.